# Modify Django admin app index

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to change the app index page so I add help text to the models themselves, e.g. under each model I want to add help text. I know that I should override `AdminSite.app_index`. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you ever had a look at http://bitbucket.org/izi/django-admin-tools/wiki/Home

Comment: This is the first time I find this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can create a new AdminSite subclass, and override app_index method to send the help text to the template. In urls.py I can use an instance of MyAdminSite instead of django's vanilla AdminSite.

```
# urls.py
from mysite.admin import MyAdminSite
site = MyAdminSite()

urlpatterns = patterns('',   
    (r'^admin/', include(site.urls)),
)

# app/admin.py
site.register(MyModel)
```

Comment: How does that solve his problem of wanting to add help text to each model?